# how to scrape all <li> instances under a specific div and process instock items

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Hi guys i have the following html and code:

```
<form class="product-form js-product-form " action="/en/cart/add" method="post">
   <fieldset class="product-form__section">
      <legend class="product-form__section-title">Choose size</legend>
      <ul class="product-sizes">
         <li>
            <input type="radio" name="id" id="product-38350" value="38350" class="product-sizes__input">
            <label for="product-38350" class="product-sizes__label">
            EU 36
            </label>
         </li>
         <li>
            <input type="radio" name="id" id="product-38351" value="38351" class="product-sizes__input">
            <label for="product-38351" class="product-sizes__label">
            EU 36.5
            </label>
         </li>
         <li>
            <input type="radio" name="id" id="product-38352" value="38352" class="product-sizes__input">
            <label for="product-38352" class="product-sizes__label">
            EU 37
            </label>
         </li>
         <li>
            <input type="radio" name="id" id="product-38353" value="38353" class="product-sizes__input">
            <label for="product-38353" class="product-sizes__label">
            EU 37.5
            </label>
         </li>
         <li>
            <input type="radio" name="id" id="product-38354" value="38354" class="product-sizes__input">
            <label for="product-38354" class="product-sizes__label">
            EU 38
            </label>
         </li>
         <li>
            <input type="radio" name="id" id="product-38355" value="38355" class="product-sizes__input" disabled="">
            <label for="product-38355" class="product-sizes__label">
            EU 38.5
            </label>
         </li>
         <li>
            <input type="radio" name="id" id="product-38356" value="38356" class="product-sizes__input">
            <label for="product-38356" class="product-sizes__label">
            EU 39
            </label>
         </li>
         <li>
            <input type="radio" name="id" id="product-38357" value="38357" class="product-sizes__input">
            <label for="product-38357" class="product-sizes__label">
            EU 39.5
            </label>
         </li>
         <li>
            <input type="radio" name="id" id="product-38358" value="38358" class="product-sizes__input">
            <label for="product-38358" class="product-sizes__label">
            EU 40
            </label>
         </li>
         <li>
            <input type="radio" name="id" id="product-38359" value="38359" class="product-sizes__input" disabled="">
            <label for="product-38359" class="product-sizes__label">
            EU 40.5
            </label>
         </li>
         <li>
            <input type="radio" name="id" id="product-38360" value="38360" class="product-sizes__input">
            <label for="product-38360" class="product-sizes__label">
            EU 41
            </label>
         </li>
         <li>
            <input type="radio" name="id" id="product-38361" value="38361" class="product-sizes__input">
            <label for="product-38361" class="product-sizes__label">
            EU 41.5
            </label>
         </li>
         <li>
            <input type="radio" name="id" id="product-38362" value="38362" class="product-sizes__input">
            <label for="product-38362" class="product-sizes__label">
            EU 42
            </label>
         </li>
         <li>
            <input type="radio" name="id" id="product-38363" value="38363" class="product-sizes__input">
            <label for="product-38363" class="product-sizes__label">
            EU 42.5
            </label>
         </li>
         <li>
            <input type="radio" name="id" id="product-38364" value="38364" class="product-sizes__input">
            <label for="product-38364" class="product-sizes__label">
            EU 43
            </label>
         </li>
         <li>
            <input type="radio" name="id" id="product-38365" value="38365" class="product-sizes__input" disabled="">
            <label for="product-38365" class="product-sizes__label">
            EU 43.5
            </label>
         </li>
         <li>
            <input type="radio" name="id" id="product-38366" value="38366" class="product-sizes__input">
            <label for="product-38366" class="product-sizes__label">
            EU 44
            </label>
         </li>
         <li>
            <input type="radio" name="id" id="product-38367" value="38367" class="product-sizes__input">
            <label for="product-38367" class="product-sizes__label">
            EU 44.5
            </label>
         </li>
         <li>
            <input type="radio" name="id" id="product-38368" value="38368" class="product-sizes__input">
            <label for="product-38368" class="product-sizes__label">
            EU 45
            </label>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </fieldset>
   <div class="product-form__actions">
      <button class="product-form__btn btn" type="submit" autocomplete="off" data-select="Select size" disabled="">
      <span>Add to cart</span>
      </button>
   </div>
</form>
```

And I use the following python:

```
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")

        sizes_json = {}

        for tag in soup.select(".product-form__section input"):
            s = tag["id"]
            i = s.index("-")
            s2 = s[i+1:].strip()
            size = tag.find_next('label').get_text(strip=True)
            sizes_json[size.replace('US', '').strip()] = s2
            sizes_json[size.replace('EU', '').strip()] = s2


        sizes_json = jjson.dumps(sizes_json)
        pids = jjson.loads(sizes_json)
        print(pids)
```

That code works and it returns all the sizes and their id in this formate:

```
{'4': '38269', 'US 4': '38269', '4.5': '38270', 'US 4.5': '38270', '5': '38271', 'US 5': '38271', '5.5': '38272', 'US 5.5': '38272', '6': '38273', 'US 6': '38273', '6.5': '38274', 'US 6.5': '38274', '7': '38275', 'US 7': '38275', '7.5': '38276', 'US 7.5': '38276', '8': '38277', 'US 8': '38277', '8.5': '38278', 'US 8.5': '38278', '9': '38279', 'US 9': '38279', '9.5': '38280', 'US 9.5': '38280', '10': '38281', 'US 10': '38281', '10.5': '38282', 'US 10.5': '38282', '11': '38283', 'US 11': '38283', '11.5': '38284', 'US 11.5': '38284', '12': '38285', 'US 12': '38285'}
```

However I only want to get the in stock values if you notice in the HTML some values contain

```
disabled=""
```

Like the EU 38.5 size so I do not want it to add that to my json how can I do this?
Also I have noticed it doesn't remove the US or EU code in some of the items how can I do these 2 things?

Comment: I updated my code that addresses both of your issues, please take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first issue regarding the disabled products you can combine the `not` and `attribute` CSS selectors in `soup.select` to exclude those elements.

As for the second issue that the country code isn't removed from the size is solved with a simple if statement.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")

sizes_json = {}

for tag in soup.select(".product-form__section input:not([disabled])"):
    s = tag["id"]
    i = s.index("-")
    s2 = s[i+1:].strip()
    size = tag.find_next('label').get_text(strip=True)
    
    if "EU" in size:
        sizes_json[size.replace('EU', '').strip()] = s2
    else:
        sizes_json[size.replace('US', '').strip()] = s2


sizes_json = json.dumps(sizes_json)
pids = json.loads(sizes_json)
print(pids)
```